# How to get Uint256 from bytes

Tags: solidity, nft, uint256

I'm learning about NFT with Solidity, and implanted some basic contract as follows.

NFTToken Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFTToken is ERC721 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;    

    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol) public ERC721(name, symbol) {}

    function _baseURI() 
        internal 
        pure 
        override 
        returns (string memory) {
        return "API_URL/api/";
    }

    function Mint(address to, bytes memory data)
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();

        _safeMint(to, newItemId, data);
        return newItemId;
    }    
}
```

Market Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Market is IERC721Receiver  {

    event DataRecieved(uint256 tokenid, string message);


    function onERC721Received(address operator,
        address from,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes memory data) public override returns (bytes4)    
    {
        emit DataRecieved(tokenId, "call recieved");       
        return this.onERC721Received.selector;
    }    
}
```

Tx happens successfully, But I'm not sure how to get price from `bytes`, I have tried different ways like

```
function GetPrice(bytes memory inBytes) pure public returns (uint256 outUint) {
      return uint256(inBytes);
}
```

But this conversion gives an error!

Comment: What is `inBytes`? Does it come from `bytes memory data`? If so, I don't believe it is standard to send the price along with a safeTransfer, but if it's abi-encoded, it needs to be decoded.

Comment: @phaze Yes, it is `bytes memory data`. I see, then how can I set the price for the token in a market contract?

Comment: I would add a custom function in Market, and call it from Mint. Re: your question, without knowing how you encoded `data` it's impossible to answer